# Jquery.print plugin hide href links

Tags: jquery, printing

we are using the jquery.print plugin [here](https://github.com/DoersGuild/jQuery.print), however it prints the links found in href tags - anyone know how to hide the links but still print the text within the link? TQ

```
$("#contentinner").print({
        globalStyles: true,
        mediaPrint: false,
        stylesheet: null,
        noPrintSelector: ".no-print",
        iframe: true,
        append: null,
        prepend: null,
        manuallyCopyFormValues: true,
        deferred: $.Deferred(),
        timeout: 750,
        title: null,
        doctype: '<!doctype html>'
});
```

EDIT - added following to global css, which hides the link but also the inner text

```
 @media print {
  a[href] { display: none; }
 }
```

EDIT - this works, thank you Sathvik @ DoersGuild

```
@media print {
   a[href]:after {
     content: none !important;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `@media` query to style your links so they may look like ordinary text in print version:

```
@media print {
    // your styles
}
```

Comment: spoke too soon - the fix hides the inner text of the link, any ideas how to just hide link but show the inner text? TQ

Comment: of course, you are hiding the link with `display: none`. Just style it like ordinary text: remove underline, pick up the proper color, remove hover effects etc. You may see it's just an ordinary string when printed.

Comment: dont want to see the link at all - just the text that the link encloses.
e.g <a href='stackoverlfow.com'>SHOW ME</a>
just need to see the text SHOW ME - however when printing using the plugin it shows the hyperlink aswell.

Comment: hmmm... I'm afraid it's not achievable through CSS only. Maybe you should try something like unwrapping via jquery or adding print version of a link in your html. But all of those are unpreferable tricks.

Comment: sorted - see above

Comment: Good to know :)